# hibernate after timeout in lightdm

Tags: lightdm, hibernate, automation

Is it possible to set up lightdm to hibernate after, for example, 5 minutes without human activity? Only in LightDM without this behaviour after login? I whant to be able just logout to lightdm by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and it would hibernate after timeout automatically instead of power off or hibernate my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but it won't be simple. First you can setup a script that runs when lightdm starts the display. Since it restarts the display when you logout, you'd write a small script that has a 5 minute timer in it that hibernates after a 5 minute delay.  You'd set lightdm.conf to run this script by editing the config file like so:

```
display-setup-script=hibernate_delay.sh
```

You could then have a second script that lightdm runs when starting a user session that would cancel the timer.  You set that in lightdm.conf as follows:

```
session-setup-script=cancel_hibernate.sh
```

As for the contents of those scripts, they could be simple. hibernate_delay.sh would be something like this, although you'd need to do the parts after the "touch" line in a second script that ran in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/hibernate_timer
sleep 300
if [ -f /tmp/hibernate_timer ];
then
  echo "5 minutes is up, hibernating"
  pmi action hibernate
else
  echo "hibernation cancelled"
fi
```

The cancel_hibernate.sh script would simply remove the hibernate_timer file so that it doesn't hibernate:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f /tmp/hibernate_timer
```

Now the theory here in my answer is sound, but I've not tried those scripts and like I mention above, the hibernate_delay.sh script needs to fork off a second script so that the sleep doesn't block. I'm sure there's also a better way to do this (using the command **at** is worth a look), but the hook-up points to lightdm would be the same.

Good Luck!

Comment: Beautiful! Big thanx! I'll try it!

Comment: it hangs up lightdm after reboot and after logout, I can see just blackscreen, but after hibernating that works perfect lightdm starts normal. I'll try to find errors in log-file.